# Matcher.group throws IndexOutOfBoundsException Exception

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I've below code and in which i am trying to print all the matches in a String using `Matcher.group()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "foo\r\nbar\r\nfoo"
                + "foo, bar\r\nak  = "
                + "foo, bar\r\nak  = "
                + "bar, bar\r\nak  = "
                + "blr05\r\nsdfsdkfhsklfh";
        //System.out.println(s);
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^ak\\s*=\\s*(\\w+)", Pattern.MULTILINE)
                .matcher(s);
        matcher.find();
        // This one works
        System.out.println("first match " + matcher.group(1));
        // Below 2 lines throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
        System.out.println("second match " + matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println("third match " + matcher.group(3));

    }
```

Above code throws **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 2** Exception.

So My question is how `Matcher.group()` works and As you can see i'll have 3 matching string, how can i print all of them using the `group()`.

Comment: You might want to set a breakpoint an inspect what `matcher` holds, how `group` and `find` interact, etc.

Comment: @luk2302 , i did use debugger but wasn't aware how `group` and `find` interact,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is clear that you have only one group :

```
^ak\\s*=\\s*(\\w+)
//          ^----^----------this is the only group
```

instead you have to use a loop for example :

```
while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println("match " + matcher.group());
}
```

---

**Outputs**

```
match = foo
match = bar
match = blr05
```

---

read about [groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html):

> **Capturing group**
>
> Parentheses group the regex between them. They capture the text matched by the regex inside them into a numbered
> group that can be reused with a numbered backreference. They allow you
> to apply regex operators to the entire grouped regex.

Comment: why there is just 1 group? how its created and can't i create multiple group so that without iterating i can print them all.

Comment: the group is defined between Parentheses so in your pattern you have just `(\\w+)` so its mean you have only one group @AmitK get it?

Answer (score 2):

You seemed to be confused by capture groups and the number of matches found in your string with the given pattern.  In the pattern you used, you only have one *capture group*:

```
^ak\\s*=\\s*(\\w+)
```

A capture group is marked using parentheses in the pattern.

If you want to retrieve every *match* of your pattern against the input string, then you should use a `while` loop:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("entire pattern: " + matcher.group(0));
    System.out.println("first capture group: " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

Each call to `Matcher#find()` will apply the pattern against the input string, from start to end, and will make available whatever matches.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you nice explanation +1.